# how to write .hex file on internal Flash ROM of microcontroller?

Tags: c, linux, embedded

I want to write a ".hex" file of size 28 kb flash on to that Internal flashROM of size 32 kb.The above mentioned question is for initialising the flashROM. What i am doing for writing that file and the code is mentioned below:

- I am having a .hex file in Intel hex format, that i have to read and write to internal 
  FlashROM of At91(8051) microcontroller.
- Open the .hex file in "rb+" mode.
- Get the length of the file and set the pointer to start address(zeroth address).
- As I need to write that file page by page and pagesize in my case is 256 bytes, I have
  divide the file by 256.
- After that I have try to write that file.

Please let me know where I am going wrong. The code is given below.

```
int a,b; int size,last_chunk; FILE *file; char *buffer1,name[20]; unsigned long fileLen;

file = fopen("flashROM.hex", "rb+");
if (!file)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file %s", name);
    return;
}

fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
fileLen=ftell(file);
printf("the file length is:%d\n",fileLen);
fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

//Allocate memory
buffer1 =(char *)malloc(fileLen+1);

if (!buffer1)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Memory error!");
            fclose(file);
    return;
}

//Read file contents into buffer
fread(buffer1, fileLen, 1, file);
/* We have to divide the entire file into chunks of 256 bytes*/
size = fileLen/256;
printf("\nsize = %d\n",size);
last_chunk = fileLen%256;
printf("\nlast chunk = %d bytes\n",last_chunk);

address = 0x0000;
printf("File upgradation should start from :%.4x",address);

for(a=0;a<=size;a++)
{
    write(fd,&buffer1,size);
    printf("Iteration=[%d]\t Data=[%x]\n",a,*buffer1);
    usleep(5000);
}
for(b=0;b<=last_chunk;b++)
{
    write(fd,&buffer1,1);
    usleep(5000);
}
```

---

After executing the binary of above mentioned program, my result is mentioned below:

```
    Writing upgrade file
    the file length is:30855

    size = 120

    last chunk = 135 bytes
    File upgradation should start from :0000
    Iteration=[0]    Data=[3a]
    Iteration=[1]    Data=[3a]
    Iteration=[2]    Data=[3a]
    Iteration=[3]    Data=[3a]
    Iteration=[4]    Data=[3a]
    Iteration=[5]    Data=[3a]
    Iteration=[6]    Data=[3a]
    Iteration=[7]    Data=[3a]
```

I don't know, why the data is always "3a", its not clear.
Please let me know where i have done wrong in programming.

Comment: Important information missing: Which µC are you targeting? Also the name Flash *ROM* (= _*R*_ead _*O*_nly _M_emory) indicates, that this may be an area of flash that's not writable.

Comment: @datenwolf But then it wouldn't be flash, would it?

Comment: @unwind: Yes it would be flash. Flash doesn't necesitate the area to be writable. It could very well be flash cells that are written in production and then using a laser the internal connection providing the writing voltage is physically severed, so that the cells no longer can be erased or written. Making some flash cells read only by cutting their writing voltage supply is cheaper than mask programming (i.e. put the data as hardwired connections onto the lithography mask). Also it allows to include bug fixes into the production of later revisions of the µC.

Comment: AT91 is a family of ARM controllers, not 8051 (that would be AT89 I think).

Comment: The 3a is the colon (:) character that starts every line in the hex file.  It comes from *buffer1 -- you never change what you are printing.

Answer (score 5):

You need a special tool that reads the `.hex` file and does whatever is necessary to write it into the flash memory of your controller (JTAG, talk to a bootloader via whatever means of communication, ...).

The tool depends on your specific microcontroller family. 8051 is not enough information, there is a huge variety of 8051s from many vendors.

Comment: i know that and in fact i am having that tool, but i want to make a utility which should work properly in linux and that utility is used in windows and the code for that utility is not available. My micontroller is of AT91 series from Atmel.

Comment: You need to convert hex to raw binary. Then read in the documentation of the microcontroller how to program its flash. It is very unlikely that you can do this with the POSIX file API.

Comment: @Ravi: The standard Linux tool for manipulating Flash over JTAG is openocd (http://openocd.sourceforge.net/) which also comes with support files for a lot of JTAG capable devices. Also JTAG doesn't work by "writing to a file". The Unix way of abstracting things to files doesn't work "just out of the box". Technically it was possible for a JTAG tool like openocd to expose the Flash "file" as files in the file system, for example using the FUSE API in Linux. But writing to a µC's flash file is different than writing to a file on a file system.

Comment: @Ravi: Also you probably don't want to implement the tool yourself; flash programming requires to happen in a very specific sequence. Just look at the source code of tools like openocd, uisp, avrdude and similar to get an idea of the amount of work neccesary. It's not difficult, just very tedious to do and why do this work in the first place if there are already existing specialized tools for the job.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `"wb+"` as your mode for [fopen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen)

Opening the file as writable will create it if it doesn't already exist.

The code where you write data also looks suspect.  You're passing a pointer to a pointer to a buffer into `write` rather than a simple pointer to your buffer.  I also don't see the pointer getting incremented so you're writing the same data repeatedly.

You could try replacing your writing code with something like the following:

```
char* ptr = buffer1;
for(a=0;a<=size;a++)
{
    write(fd,ptr,size);
    ptr+=size;
    printf("Iteration=[%d]\t Data=[%x]\n",a,*buffer1);
    usleep(5000);
}
for(b=0;b<=last_chunk;b++)
{
    write(fd,ptr,1);
    usleep(5000);
}
```

Comment: i have the rb+ to wb+, but right i am getting filelength as 0 and last_chunk also 0(which is not the desired o/p).

Comment: I may have misunderstood your problem.  Your question starts by saying that you want to write data to a file but your code appears to be trying to read data from an existing file.  If you're creating a file, it'll be correct that there is no data in the newly created file.  If you're reading an existing file, my suggestion was wrong and you could keep using `"rb+"` as the file mode.

Comment: it wont work as i have to read that filelength and using write system call, i have write that file on flashROM.

Comment: I don't understand.  Are you trying to create a new file or read an exiting one?

Comment: Ok, seems like my answer won't be useful then.  I'll delete my answer soon.  I suggest you update your question to be clearer that you want to open an existing file.  It would also be good if you were much more specific about where the first problem exists in your code.

Comment: Oh, and it'd also be useful for you to get into the habit of checking the error codes returned from standard C functions.  You currently ignore errors returned from everything after fopen.

Comment: my first problem is existing in write system call, which i think.That's why i am getting 3a's in every memory location in my FlashROM.Can u have a look and let me know where i am going wrong???

Comment: @Ravi I've updated my answer with comments on your use of `write`